# How to get rid of artifacts in corners - Bevel Object

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects, bezier-curves

I am trying to model a swimming pool. I create a rectangular loop (first curve) and a wall profile (second curve). I used the second curve as Bevel Object on the first curve, but it creates strange artifacts in the corners.

Could anyone tell me how I can fix it?

[image: Problem example]

[image]

Comment: Maybe if you set the origin on the second curve to be at the bottom point of it.

Comment: I've found that if you make the 1st curve a rectangle (not rounded) then the artifacts disappear. But to have a slightly rounded rectangle, I have no solution.

Comment: The segments of the curve at the corners are too close to each other. If you convert that to mesh you'll see that in [more details](https://imgur.com/NE3R2K4) (curve segment deleted). I can think of only moving them slightly out from the corner. You could do that after converting to mesh and using `Bridge Edge Loops` to connect them with precise.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

Moving your Bezier Curve's origin (that you use as your Bevel Object) to the "outside" of your Curve will solve your problem:
[image: Fixed Example]

Your Origin is now "in the middle of" your Bezier Curve so that your Bevel Object can't be moved along your rectangular path without these artifacts.